# regular expression to match -100 to 0

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to match all numbers inclusive between -100 and 0.

So valid values are:

- 0
- -100
- -40

Invalid are:

- 1
- 100
- 40

Thank you!

Comment: This needs to be a regular expression? You can't do numeric < or > comparisons?

Comment: Agreed, this is not an appropriate use of a regular expression.  How will you handle -1e+2? -0.05?

Comment: It could just be a number contained in a bigger string (log file or who knows) which needs to be matched there instead of being extracted and treated after (which you would probably do with a regexp anyway)

Comment: I need to use it for an asp requiredvalidator function and keep consistent with the other validators currently in place.  I know, not the best, but in this case being consistent in this code is more important right now.

Comment: Using the asp.net RangeValidator is out of the question?

Comment: How about -0 and -04?  Are those valid values?

Comment: Abe - thank you, never thought of that.

Answer (score 8):

Use this function:

```
/^(?:0|-100|-[1-9]\d?)$/
```

Comment: **This is wrong.** You need to group the alternation to prevent the `^` and `$` markers from being included with the first and last options. i.e. `^(?:0|-100|-\d\d?)$`

Comment: Also, as commented by Aaron on the question, this will currently match -0 and -04. Need to use `[1-9]` in place of the first `\d` to avoid that.

Comment: You're very right peter, updated my answer with your corrections

Answer (score 2):

OK, so I'm late, but here goes:

```
(?:         # Either match:
 -          # a minus sign, followed by
 (?:        # either...    
  100       # 100
  |         # or
  [1-9]\d?  # a number between 1 and 99
 )
 |          # or...
 (?<!-)     # (unless preceded by a minus sign)
 \b0        # the number 0 on its own
)
\b          # and make sure that the number ends here.
(?!\.)      # except in a decimal dot.
```

This will find negative integer numbers (-100 to -1) and 0 in normal text. No leading zeroes allowed.

If you already have the number isolated, then

```
^(?:-(?:100|[1-9]\d?)|0)$
```

is enough if you don't want to allow leading zeroes or `-0`.

If you don't care about leading zeroes or `-0`, then use

```
^-?0*(?:100|\d\d?)$
```

...Now what do you do if your boss tells you "Oh, by the way, from tomorrow on, we need to allow values between `-184.78` and `33.53`"?

Comment: upvoted for the detailed comments.  Uncommented regex are a pain to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Try ^(-[1-9][0-9]?|-100|0)$

But perhaps it would be simpled to cast it to numeric and quickly check the range then

Answer (score 0):

How about using a capture group and then programmatically testing the value e.g.

```
(-?\p{Digit}{1,3})
```

and then testing the captured value to ensure that it is within your range?

Comment: Depending on how the match is done, this might also match `-99` within `-999`, so to be safe, better surround this by anchors. Otherwise that's probably what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to regular expressions would this work?
`(-100|((-[1-9]?[0-9])|\b0))`